# How to construct oracle.sql.ANYDATA in Java and pass it in PL/SQL procedure

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I'm looking for a code on how to construct an ANYDATA object in Java, and then pass it in a PL/SQL procedure.
Any code will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Oracle documentation for the `ANYDATA` class](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/ANYDATA.html) explains how to create an ANYDATA object:

```
    NUMBER number = new NUMBER(12345);
    ANYDATA myAnyDataObject = ANYDATA.convertDatum(number);
```

To pass the created value to a stored procedure, use `CallableStatement.setObject`:

```
    CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call anydata_proc(?)}");
    cstmt.setObject(1, myAnyDataObject);
    cstmt.execute();
```